# How to stub a module method for rspec testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

So I have a test that I would like to mock a method with fake activerecord results, but my method isn't being stubbed.

I'm trying to test a module method, so I'm doing the following:

```
describe JobRenewalCopyExports do

  let(:renewal_helper) { Class.new { include Ps::Renewal::RenewalItems::RenewalItemHelper } }

  it 'get_next_plan_year_first_run_date' do

    export_transactions = [fake_data]
     renewal_helper.any_instance.stubs(:export_transactions_that_have_transport).returns(export_transactions)
    next_run_date = renewal_helper.get_next_plan_year_first_run_date(1)
    ...
 end
```

The problem is that when my test runs, the renewal_helper *export_transactions_that_have_transport* method in the module is being run, so it's not returning the fake_data I specified in the test.

Comment: That should work.  What do you mean it "doesn't fire"... do you get an error or is the each block simply not executed?

Comment: Good timing Steve, you are right, it works as a stub, but the problem is the method export_transactions_that_have_transport isn't being stubbed, the module method still executes.  I'll update my question.